# Optimizing PDO for multiple rows

Tags: arrays, sqlite

I'm trying to optimize a small piece of code, wrote in PHP, that actually is too slow to execute.

This piece of code should take a database, and renumber the column called "task_number" from 1 to x, where x is the number of active tasks into the database.

This is the code. It works with a SQLlite db.

```
//Step 1: retrieve from the database all "Active" rows IDs 
$stmt = $this->pdo->query('SELECT id FROM tabella WHERE stato = :STATO ORDER BY task_number ASC');
$stmt->bindValue(':STATO', "Active");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Here we have an array with all IDs.
   
//Step 2: renumber the tasks starting from 1
$renumber = 1;
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('UPDATE tabella SET task_number = :TASK_NUMBER WHERE id = :ID');
$stmt->bindParam(':ID', $id);
$stmt->bindParam(':TASK_NUMBER', $renumber);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $stmt->execute();
    $renumber++;
}
```

Actually it works, but it is very slow.

BEFORE running code:

| ID (primary key) | task_number | task_content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2 | Alfa |
| 1003 | 4 | Bravo |
| 1009 | 1 | Omega |
| 1234 | -3 | Charlie |

AFTER:

| ID (primary key) | task_number | task_content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 | Alfa |
| 1003 | 2 | Bravo |
| 1009 | 3 | Omega |
| 1234 | 4 | Charlie |

Is there a way to pass arrays instead of values to the `prepare` statement?
More or less, my intetion is this:

```
$renumber = 1;
$id_array = array();
$renumber_array = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    array_push($id_array, $row['id']);
    array_push($renumber_array, $renumber);
    $renumber++;
}
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('UPDATE tabella SET task_number = ($renumber_array) WHERE id = ($id_array)');
$stmt->execute();
```